# Why there are so many problems with the overheating and fan speed when installing Linux?

Tags: kernel, system-installation, hardware, fan

I don't understand it. Almost every 10th or 20th question is about fan or overheating or that the fan is too loud and the speed too big etc.

And these questions are not only about laptops but often about desktop Linux systems.

Why there are so many problems with fans in the Linux world?

Why is it so hard to set the right fan speed in Linux distributions or during the install process?

Comment: I installed linux on many computers but they don't have any FAN problems!

Comment: @SepahradSalour Well, my laptop and desktop are from HP and they both had fan problems. Maybe you were just a lucky person. And btw. there is no need to shout at me in this case. Thank you.

Comment: I have never experienced this tendency and don't think this question can be answered the way it is formulated.

Comment: @T.F. Well, using your logic I have never crashed with my car so far, so the assumption would be that I am a good driver or my car is good? Absolutely not, I have just been a little luckier than that guy who crashed. I think a little humility would be OK for you and you-like "sovereign" people. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

> I don't understand it. Almost every 10th or 20th question is about fan or overheating or that the fan is too loud and the speed to big etc.

I think if we did a more realistic survey this would prove a *grotesque* exaggeration.  I monitor this site a lot, and while there are hundreds of questions per day, this most recent overheating question is the first one I've noticed in weeks (of me watching, not real time), so realistically, it is more likely that no more than one in 20,000 questions has to do with overheating.  I'd also bet that of those, the majority in the end turn out to be hardware issues that have nothing to do with linux or any other OS.

Just glancing at the "Related" questions in the sidebar, and considering "fan" and "overheating" are in your title, it would seem there have been very few questions of this sort. O_O?

> Why there are so many problems with fans in the Linux world?

There aren't.  I've been a user for ~15 years, including work as a professional, with dozens of systems and *never once* personally seen a linux related fan or heating problem.  I'd bet if you surveyed linux users generally, 99% of them would say the same thing.

Comment: Just because you haven't seen doesn't mean there aren't. There ARE problems with linux and even after last 6 kernel updates I have done, some problems persist. My laptop becomes a hot furnace when I run linux.